# LEDs bulbs flicker when 3rd added

Tags: electrical, lighting, led

I have 3 G4 light sockets built into my kitchen cabinets, to provide downlights onto the counters.

The bulbs would always go out really quickly, but might start working again for a bit if i tapped the cupboard.

Today at the DIY shop i spotted some 1.8W 200 lumen LED G4 bulbs so i thought I'd give them a try.

I put two and tested the lights, which lit up happily. I then added the third and retested. The LEDs all started flickering. They flicker if 3 bulbs are installed, but are happy with 1 or 2.

It doesn't matter which socket is the empty one.

What's happening here? Is my wiring safe?

Comment: Is there a dimmer involved?  Is this 12v or 120v (I believe there are G4 base bulbs in both voltages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't quote me but look into dimmer switch if any for led. Sounds like not enough current or wiring issue. Do you have a multimeter to test the current? Do different bulbs work (3)

Comment: The halogen bulbs work, but then go very quickly. I think I need a new transformer.